# What is the purpose of setHeader and setProperty in Apache Camel?

Tags: apache-camel

Sorry I'm new to Camel. Looking at the documentation of these two methods, there is no meaningful indication of when you might want to use these methods.

E.g. setProperty() see [https://camel.apache.org/components/3.19.x/eips/setProperty-eip.html](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.4.x/eips/setProperty-eip.html)

I don't see any property methods other than setting them and removing them. What is the point? Same for headers, you can set them, but no idea how to get them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Sorry I'm new to Camel. Looking at the documentation of these two methods, there is no meaningful indication of when you might want to use these methods.

To understand when you want to use these methods, you need to understand the difference between *Headers* and *Properties*.

`org.apache.camel.Message` — The fundamental entity containing the data being carried and routed in Camel.

Messages are the entities used by systems to communicate with each other when using messaging channels. Messages flow in one direction, from a sender to a receiver.

[Messages](https://livebook.manning.com/book/camel-in-action-second-edition/chapter-1/147) have a body (a payload), ***headers***, and optional attachments.

- Headers are values associated with the message, such as sender identifiers, hints about content encoding, authentication information, and so on.
- Headers are name-value pairs; the name is a unique, case-insensitive string, and the value is of type java.lang.Object.
- Camel imposes no constraints on the type of the headers.
- There are also no constraints on the size of headers or on the number of headers included with a message.
- Headers are stored as a map within the message.

A message can also have optional attachments, which are typically used for the web service and email components.

`org.apache.camel.Exchange` — An exchange in Camel is the message’s container during routing. An exchange also provides support for the various types of interactions between systems, also known as message exchange patterns (MEPs). Read more about MEPs [here](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/faq/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html#top).

A Camel [exchange](https://livebook.manning.com/book/camel-in-action-second-edition/chapter-1/160) has an ID, MEP, exception, and ***properties***. It also has an in message to store the incoming message, and an out message to store the reply.

- Properties are similar to message headers, but they last for the duration of the entire exchange.
- Properties are used to contain global-level information, whereas message headers are specific to a particular message.
- Camel itself adds various properties to the exchange during routing.
- You, as a developer, can store and retrieve properties at any point during the lifetime of an exchange.

So with this understanding - now based on your usecase you need to decide whether to save your 'type' (i.e., values that you want to save) either in Headers or Properties.

> I don't see any property methods other than setting them and removing them. What is the point? Same for headers, you can set them, but no idea how to get them.

To retrieve either headers or properties, use either of the following

1. [Simple expression language](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.19.x/languages/simple-language.html)
2. [Header language](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.19.x/languages/header-language.html)
3. [Exchange language](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.19.x/languages/exchangeProperty-language.html)
4. [Bind language](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.19.x/languages/bean-language.html)

Maybe there are more ways, but these quite a lot and widely used (atleast by me!).

Update: You can access exchange properties that you've set using exchangeProperties from Simple, few examples below,

```
from("seda:updateCustomer").routeId("update-customers-details")
    .setProperty("customerId").simple("${header.customerId}")
    .setProperty("requestBody").body()
    .setProperty("someConstant").constant(123)
    // You can access the properties with exchangeProperty method using simple language 
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Value of customerId from exchange: ${exchangeProperty.customerId}")
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Request body saved in exchange: ${exchangeProperty.requestBody}")
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Value of someConstant in exchange: ${exchangeProperty.someConstant}")
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Value of exchangeId: ${exchangeId}")
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Value of entire exchange: ${exchange}")
    ..
    ..
```

Source: https://livebook.manning.com/book/camel-in-action-second-edition/chapter-1/

Comment: Thanks. So, to access a Property you need to write for example a Processor, because a Processor has access to the Exchange. The Exchange is generally just not that easily accessed along a route (you cannot use Simple for example).

Comment: No, you can access the properties that you have saved in your exchange with exchangeProperty using [Simple](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.4.x/languages/simple-language.html) in a route. I've added few examples for you in the answer.

Comment: Nice and complete answer Vijay Kunar wrote in here. Just to complement, Camel also offers a fluent builder to read a property: exchangeProperty("customerId"), for instance.

Comment: Awesome Vijay, I have not see (or noticed?) exchangeProperty until now, very useful

Comment: Thanks Vijay. One thing: using header language works for property? If I use `header(key)` or `simple("${header.key}")` but there is a message header with the same key and also in exchange property, what values will be fetched? 
Also want to mention that `@ExchangeProperties Map<String, Object> properties` is available in bean binding so that you just add this arg in your method signature and you have access to the exchange properties.

Answer (score 2):

Headers (`.setHeader`) are usually set when sending messages to other components/systems that would require or need them, like Message Brokers, JMS, Web Services, HTTP, FTP server etc. Most Camel components forward all exchange headers by default. Supposing you have a sensitive data in the headers, it'd be propagated!

Exchange Properties (`.setProperty`) can be used to hold data you might need during the exchange's lifecycle, without worrying about propagating their values to other systems.

In an HTTP request, for instance, you must define a method (GET, POST etc), likely as a header. So, it makes sense to set it as a header! On the other hand, data retrieved from this call might be "saved" in a property to be easily reused during the routing steps.